# Using serilog´s ForContext in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, logging, mvvmcross, serilog

I am using xamarin MvvmCross and configured serilog as the logger.
I am trying to add custom variables to the template passing them in the context, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

This is my serilog configuration:

```
var local = Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;
string path = Path.Combine(local, "my_log.txt");

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .WriteTo.File(path,
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} {myCustomVar} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}")
    .CreateLogger();
```

And here in my ViewModel I am trying to log a message:

```
using (_logProvider.OpenMappedContext("myCustomVar","varValue"))
            {
                _log.Info("Good Morning");
            }
```

The line output to my_log.txt does not contain a value for "myCustomVar".

The only way I have found to make it work is bypass totally MvvmCross and write a custom logger that directly calls  serilog like this:

```
    public interface ILogService
    {
        void LogMessage(string message);
    }
```

and the android implementation:

```
public class LogService : ILogService
    {
        public void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            Log.ForContext("myCustomVar", "varValue")
                        .Information(message);
        }
    }
```

There is a way to access the advanced features of serilog such as passing variables in the context using the MvvmCross/IMvx logging abstraction layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [connect Serilog and MvvmCross together](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging#extend-it-with-custom-log-providers) for it to work, and you also need to [enrich with properties from the log context](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) because of the way that the MvvmCross integration was implemented (they don't call `ForContext`, and instead they call `PushProperty`).

Override the `GetDefaultLogProviderType` in your platform project's `Setup.cs`:

```
public override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType() => MvxLogProviderType.Serilog;
```

And create an `IMvxLogProvider` from the Serilog logger you create:

```
protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
{
    var local = Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;
    string path = Path.Combine(local, "my_log.txt");

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
      .Enrich.FromLogContext()
      .WriteTo.File(path,
          rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
          outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} {myCustomVar} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}")
      .CreateLogger();

      return base.CreateLogProvider();
}
```